# Create an interface or class definition with a strong typed constructor

Tags: typescript

I want to create a interface or class definition with a strong typed constructor. I see similar questions, how ever, still I can't create one.

I try like:

```
// maybe in a .d.ts file
declare interface MyInterface{
  // constructor(conArg: string) : ImplementInterface // this not works - Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(conArg: string) => ImplementInterface'
  // new(conArg : string) : ImplementInterface        // this not works - Type 'ImplementInterface' provides no match for the signature 'new (conArg: string): ImplementInterface'
  // new(conArg : string) : MyInterface               // this not works - Type 'ImplementInterface' provides no match for the signature 'new (conArg: string): MyInterface'
  myMethod(myArg : string) : string
}
declare class MyClass {
  constructor(conArg: string)
  myMethod(myArg : string) : string
}



// implementations
// using class
class ImplementClass implements MyClass{
  // constructor(){}      // not error, when un-comment or commentted :(
                          // expected behavior : error constructor is missing / constructor required at less one param
  myMethod(){ return '' } // comment this line throw a error, is expected :)
}
// using interface
class ImplementInterface implements MyInterface {
  // constructor(){}      // not error, when un-comment or commentted :(
                          // expected behavior : error constructor is missing / constructor required at less one param
  myMethod(){ return '' } // comment this line throw a error, is expected :)
}
```

Comment: Interfaces describe the type of an *instance* of the class. Instances don't (at least, they shouldn't) have construct signatures.

Comment: Objects in TS don't have strongly-typed `constructor` properties for reasons laid out in [ms/TS#3841](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) and class declarations don't support `implements`-like clauses for the static side as per [ms/TS#33892](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892).  ...

Comment: ... (Also note: a no-arg constructor is assignable to a one-arg constructor, see [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters), so you should change that). Both of these together make what you're doing hard to write ergonomically; you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND8ozN), which is ‍♂️. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ok but, if I can't use a declaration of interface or a class, how I type a constructor?

Comment: ImplementInterface satisfies MyInterfaceConstuctor; is almost. But if comment the constructor : // constructor(otherArg: number) { }    no errors :(     however, is more close than have a 'any' constructor

Comment: As I said above, a zero-arg constructor is assignable to a one-arg constructor, see [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  It is intentionally behaving that way, and this is essentially beside your point.  You'd have the same thing with [this](https://tsplay.dev/N737oN).  Could you please [edit] your question to remove that issue from it?  Otherwise this question is talking about completely unrelated things that are only related because both of them are happening with your code.

Comment: Please let me know how to proceed here.

Comment: Before this responses... I belive than was possible but I don't know how.  Please post a response.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand you.  I had suggested you [edit] the question to not ask about the zero-arg constructor; for example, you could say that `constructor(wrongArg: number){}` does not yield the expected error.  I could do the edit for you, if you'd like.  Do I your permission to do that?  After the edit I'll post an answer.